WSO2 IS 7.0.0 for MFA - Could not convert socket to TLS javax.mail.MessagingException
I am trying to configure the multi factor authentication with WSO2 Identity Server 7.0.0. I have provided below information in deployment.toml file
[output_adapter.email]
from_address= "coolkrishna@gmail.com"
username= "CoolKrishna"
password= "password"
hostname= "smtp.gmail.com"
port= 25
enable_start_tls= true
enable_authentication= false
signature = "ABC.com"

But the I am getting below exception while email is triggered.
 {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter} - Exception occurred when sending email to abhishek@gmail.com. Could not convert socket to TLS javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
      nested exception is:
            javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2155)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:752)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
            at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter$EmailSender.run(EmailEventAdapter.java:367)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1426)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1336)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:421)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:626)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:553)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2150)
            ... 12 more
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
            at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
            at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
            ... 26 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
            at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
            at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
            at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)


It appears that the identity server cannot find the certificate of the mail host in the client's trust store. To resolve this issue, you need to properly import the certificates on the identity server node.
Follow steps below to obtain the certificate and import it into the client-truststore in WSO2 Identity Server (IS-HOME/repository/resources/security):

Obtain the certificate from the mail server:

 openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <mail-server-hostname>:<port> -starttls smtp


Import the certificate into the client trust store:

keytool -import -alias <alias-name> -file <cert-name> -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon

Hope this will help to resolve this issue.
